# Image And Div Don't Resize Together

Tags: css

I have an image that is set to width=120% with position=relative inside a div. The div is set to width=50% with 6% margins and has a min width of 300px. When I resize the browser window and make it smaller, the image and div get smaller together. But at a certain point the image stops getting smaller and becomes larger compared to the div, breaking the design (see below). How can I fix this problem so that the image and div will always resize together?
Thank you

`_______         ___________
| image |       |    image  |
|_______|       |___________| 
| div   | --->    |       | 
| with  |         | div   |
| text  |         |       |
|_______|         |_______|`

Here is the HTML code:

```
<article id="content">
<div id="Photo">
<img src="images/A04.jpg" width="126%" />               
</div> 
<p> text </p>
</article>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
#content {
width: 50%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 6% 1% 6%;
background-color: #f8f8f8; 
border: 1px solid #ccc; 
min-width: 500px;
}

#Photo {
text-align: center;
position: relative;
right: 13.1%;
}
```

Comment: No code shared, no answer given.

Comment: Hi josefb122, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please show us the code you are having issues with. Include all relevant code, simplify if you can or put up a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: please give us the code, so let us help you

Answer (score 0):

You would have a much easier time setting the image to be a background image and using the cover property. You can still set the background position to be 13% right.

```
<article id="content">
    <div id="Photo">
    </div> 
    <p> text </p>
</article>    


#content {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 6% 1% 6%;
    background-color: #f8f8f8; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    min-width: 500px;
}

#Photo {
    background-image: url();
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center 13%;
}
```

Comment: I do not want the image to get cropped when resizing the browser window, that's why I don't use a background image. Is there a way to do it like I did with an image and prevent it from breaking the design when resizing to min-width?

Comment: Ah, ok I'm understanding the issue better now. Your image (all images) has a fixed aspect ratio. You want it to stay within a container of a changing width, you require the height to scale in proportion. When you switch to a fixed width, because of your min-width, it will bust out of the div so that it does not become distorted (breaking the aspect ratio).

Comment: So the answer is no, you can not scale an image without distortion (altering the aspect ratio) in both directions when one direction is fixed. Because geometry. Your answers are to crop or distort.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can tell the image to stop scaling when it reaches the min-width and stay at a given size, for example 200px wide and 100px tall?

Comment: Yes, you can write a media query. You might want to find the screen width where it hits 200px wide with some dev tools, then write a style that makes your img that fixed size at that given screen width.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries